# Django ImageField is not being updated while submiting a form

Tags: django, django-forms, imagefield

## Issue describrion

I have a model which describes a UserProfile and a dedicated form to allow user to update the model. Except `photo`(ImageField), everything is working fine. Issue with `photo` field is that the image is not being changed at all with `EditProfileForm`. In other words I have same image attached to this field before and after form submition, the `photo` is pointing to the same picture, and nothing new was uploaded to the server.
It is worth to be noted that `photo` field is working through the form from admin panel.
No issues with other fields related to `UserProfile` and `User`: all of them can be updated, and the update is saved in database.

## Environment details

For a time being I am using Django in version 4.0.3 running with `DEBUG=True` and build in development server.

## Code

```
### Models
def get_image_save_path(
        instance,
        filename:str
        ) -> str:
    save_dir = instance.__class__.__name__
    file_name = uuid.uuid4().hex
    file_extension = pathlib.Path(filename).suffix
    return f"{save_dir}/{file_name}{file_extension}".lower()

def validate_image_size(image):
    if not image:
        raise ValidationError("No image found")
    if image.size > 512*1024:
        raise ValidationError("Max size is 512kb")

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                related_name='user_profile',
                                primary_key=True)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_save_path,
                                    verbose_name="Photo", 
                                    validators=[validate_image_size],
                                    default="userprofile/default_photo.jpg",
                                    null=False,
                                    blank=False)
    bio = models.TextField(default='', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username}"

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(
        sender:ModelBase,
        instance:User,
        created:bool,
        **kwargs:Dict) -> None:
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        return

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(
    sender: ModelBase,
    instance: User,
    **kwargs: Dict) -> None:
    instance.user_profile.save()
```

```
### Forms
class EditUserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class EditProfileForm(ModelForm):
    photo = ImageField(widget=FileInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control-file'}))
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('photo', 'bio')
```

```
### Views
@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    return render(request, 
                    template_name="accounts/profile_view.html",
                    context = {})

@login_required
def profile_edit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userForm = EditUserForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profileForm = EditProfileForm(data=request.POST, 
                                      files=request.FILES, 
                                      instance=request.user.user_profile)
        if userForm.is_valid() and profileForm.is_valid():
            profileForm.save()
            userForm.save()
            return redirect('accounts_app:profile_view')
    else:
        userForm = EditUserForm(instance=request.user)
        profileForm = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user.user_profile)
        context = {"userForm": userForm, "profileForm": profileForm, }
        return render(request, 'accounts/edit_profile.html', context)
```

```
### Template
{% block content %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="panel panel-primary panel-login rounded-lg">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <form class="" action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {% for field in userForm %}
        <p>
          {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
          {{ field }}
          {% if field.help_text %}
            <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
          {% endif %}
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </p>
        {% endfor %}

        {% for field in profileForm %}
        <p>
          {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
          {{ field }}
          {% if field.help_text %}
            <small style="color: grey">{{ field.help_text }}</small>
          {% endif %}
          {% for error in field.errors %}
            <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
          {% endfor %}
        </p>
        {% endfor %}
      <button class="btn btn-danger standard-btn" type="submit">Zapisz zmiany</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

## Question

What I did wrong in the code, that is causing and described issue with `photo` field?

Answer (score 0):

try this

use multipart/form-data when your form includes any  elements

in templates

```
  <form class="" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: I spent a few hours looking for a solution, looking for answers in documentation, guides, etc. I felt that the solution would be simple and that I had missed something, but I didn't think it would be that simple.
Thanks a lot, everything works. Problem solved.